# Execute each QTModbus response in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, modbus

I'm developing Modbus application.
Sending read requests like this.

```
void MainWindow::readData(int start,int len){

    QModbusDataUnit readUnit(QModbusDataUnit::InputRegisters,start,len);
    if (auto *reply = modbusDevice->sendReadRequest(readUnit,modbusAddr)) {
        if (!reply->isFinished())
            connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::readReady);
        else
            delete reply; // broadcast replies return immediately
    }
}
```

As I have many read requests at the same time, I believe responses are 'stuck' in some kind of queue executing each `readReady` one-by-one, which is a bit slow.

I would like to execute each `readReady` in its own thread.
Any way I could do it?
Or, perhaps, this would be 'a bad practice'?

I've tried using QtConcurrent::run in `readReady` slot, but this doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue comes from `readReady()`.

As soon as a `QModbusClient::sendReadRequest()` is completed, you call the `readReady()` callback. You cannot go faster than the time it takes to the request to finish.

If we take a look at the [`QModbusClient` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodbusclient.html#details), we can see this note:

> Note: QModbusClient queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. For example, the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms issues 6 requests in parallel for one host/port combination.

As you mentioned that you have *"many requests at the same time"*, this may explain your issue.

Actually I believe that the queuing you noticed is not about the `readyRead()` calls but about the `QModbusClient` side instead.

Using multi-threading for the callback calls would not help since you cannot "put the cart before the horse" :)

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. I don't fully understand what does "he number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the PROTOCOL" mean. Isn't Modbus a protocol itself... 
In my situation I use serial port for data transfer.

Comment: @User45234 To be honest, I never used the Modbus protocol and I'm not that aware of how it works. But from what I can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus), there are many variants of Modbus protocols. Since Modbus is at the layer-7 (the highest level) on the OSI model, I guess the lower layers can be implemented a lot of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

With Modbus RTU, over a serial connection, to send a request you first have to wait to receive the response from the previous one.

You cannot send several requests at once, a serial connection cannot control the collisions that this generates.

It would be possible using Modbus/TCP as long as slaves are able to handle a request queue, but not all devices can do that.